# Jmeter Script executes but threads are not finishing

Tags: linux, api, performance, testing, jmeter

We are running jmeter performance test scripts on Linux servers. It executes and produces results but threads are not finishing since the beginning of steps . We see FINISHED = 0 in the initial steps and of some value at the end.
Any feedback on why threads are not finishing ?

Sample test result

sh apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t "PKS10-test-060221.jmx" -l jmeter_log.log  -JL7.rampup=10 -JL7.duration=900 -JL7.thread_delay=0 -JL7.validations_per_issuance=100 -JL7.threads=75 | tee jmeter_console.log
Creating summariser 
Created the tree successfully using PKS10-test-060221.jmx
Starting the test
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
summary + 1560 in 15.1s = 103.2/s Avg: 471 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary + 4846 in 30s = 161.5/s Avg: 463 Min: 224 Max: 1619 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 6406 in 45.1s = 142.0/s Avg: 465 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4500 in 30s = 150.0/s Avg: 500 Min: 223 Max: 1954 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 10906 in 75.1s = 145.2/s Avg: 480 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4731 in 30s = 157.7/s Avg: 475 Min: 223 Max: 1824 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 15637 in 105s = 148.8/s Avg: 478 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4537 in 30s = 151.2/s Avg: 496 Min: 204 Max: 2109 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 20174 in 135s = 149.3/s Avg: 482 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4687 in 30s = 156.2/s Avg: 479 Min: 223 Max: 2064 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 24861 in 165s = 150.6/s Avg: 482 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4642 in 30s = 154.7/s Avg: 484 Min: 223 Max: 1754 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 29503 in 195s = 151.2/s Avg: 482 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4521 in 30s = 150.7/s Avg: 497 Min: 197 Max: 2167 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 34024 in 225s = 151.1/s Avg: 484 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4662 in 30s = 155.4/s Avg: 483 Min: 224 Max: 1712 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 38686 in 255s = 151.6/s Avg: 484 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4478 in 30s = 149.2/s Avg: 503 Min: 221 Max: 2655 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 43164 in 285s = 151.4/s Avg: 486 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4355 in 30s = 145.2/s Avg: 516 Min: 222 Max: 2079 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 47519 in 315s = 150.8/s Avg: 489 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4682 in 30s = 155.8/s Avg: 479 Min: 223 Max: 2092 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 52201 in 345s = 151.2/s Avg: 488 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4466 in 30.1s = 148.3/s Avg: 505 Min: 213 Max: 3105 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 56667 in 375s = 151.0/s Avg: 489 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4461 in 30s = 149.5/s Avg: 503 Min: 223 Max: 2508 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 61128 in 405s = 150.9/s Avg: 490 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 3926 in 30s = 130.9/s Avg: 573 Min: 223 Max: 2266 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 65054 in 435s = 149.5/s Avg: 495 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4635 in 30s = 154.4/s Avg: 486 Min: 223 Max: 1854 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 69689 in 465s = 149.8/s Avg: 494 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4287 in 30s = 142.9/s Avg: 524 Min: 222 Max: 2324 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 73976 in 495s = 149.4/s Avg: 496 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4997 in 30s = 166.6/s Avg: 447 Min: 195 Max: 2201 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 78973 in 525s = 150.4/s Avg: 493 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4985 in 30s = 166.2/s Avg: 452 Min: 222 Max: 2160 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 83958 in 555s = 151.2/s Avg: 491 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4795 in 30s = 159.8/s Avg: 470 Min: 201 Max: 2118 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 88753 in 585s = 151.7/s Avg: 489 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4899 in 30.1s = 162.9/s Avg: 458 Min: 221 Max: 2347 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 93652 in 615s = 152.2/s Avg: 488 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4715 in 30s = 157.6/s Avg: 477 Min: 222 Max: 2109 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 98367 in 645s = 152.5/s Avg: 487 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4602 in 30s = 153.4/s Avg: 488 Min: 222 Max: 2142 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 102969 in 675s = 152.5/s Avg: 487 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4724 in 30s = 157.5/s Avg: 476 Min: 202 Max: 3099 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 107693 in 705s = 152.7/s Avg: 487 Min: 192 Max: 3710 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 3963 in 30s = 132.1/s Avg: 567 Min: 193 Max: 3743 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 111656 in 735s = 151.9/s Avg: 490 Min: 192 Max: 3743 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4840 in 30s = 161.3/s Avg: 463 Min: 222 Max: 2726 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 116496 in 765s = 152.3/s Avg: 489 Min: 192 Max: 3743 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 4493 in 30s = 149.7/s Avg: 501 Min: 222 Max: 2199 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
summary = 120989 in 795s = 152.2/s Avg: 489
summary = 135136 in 885s = 152.7/s Avg: 488 Min: 192 Max: 3743 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 2313 in 15.4s = 150.2/s Avg: 495 Min: 222 Max: 2085 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 75 Finished: 75
summary = 137449 in 901s = 152.6/s Avg: 488 Min: 192 Max: 3743 Err: 0 (0.00%)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at output of JMeter's [summariser](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode) which shows the number of

- number of started threads
- number of active threads
- number of finished threads
- number of executed samplers
- throughput
- average, minimum and maximum response times
- percentage of errors.

It looks like you're running your test with 75 threads (virtual users), once JMeter launches the thread it starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). When there are no more samplers to execute and loops to iterate the thread is being shut down.

So `Finished: 0` lines mean that there are 75 active threads which are executing Samplers and none of them has finished its job yet.